# Como executar instuções de uma string

Tags: c#, .net, eval

Eu tenho uma string:

```
string str="for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) Console.Write(\"hello\");"
```

Como eu fasso para executar as instruções dessa string?

```
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) Console.Write("hello");
```

Comment: Esta questão já foi respondida [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4800267/6194013) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4800292) Eu sugeria que olhasse para o source code do dynamiclinq no github que tem lá vários exemplos onde compilam e executam o código de seguida usando dynamic expressions. [aqui tens um exemplo](https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic/blob/master/Src/System.Linq.Dynamic.Test/DynamicExpressionTests.cs)

Comment: eu coloquei o `using System.CodeDom;` e o `using System.CodeDom.Compile` e mesmo assim o codigo ainda está faltando referencias, ele usa alguma outra referencia? estou usando .net 3.1 eu acho.